# How nested interface in a class behave like?

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

For below code,

```
interface SuperInterface{
    void f();
    interface StaticNestedInterface{    
    }
}

class Sub implements SuperInterface{
    public void f(){

    }
}

public class Dummy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub x  = new Sub();
    }

}
```

Compiler does not ask `class Sub` to implement `interface StaticNestedInterface`.

Is `class Sub` a valid java code?

Comment: If it compiles, it's valid. The nested interface is still just another interface, it's name is just qualified by the outer interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its a valid Java code. 
You are just declaring `StaticNestedInterface` in `SuperInterface`. One way to use nested interface would be

```
interface SuperInterface {
    void f();

    StaticNestedInterface sni();

    interface StaticNestedInterface {
        void a();
    }
}


class Sub implements SuperInterface{
    public void f(){

    }

    @Override
    public StaticNestedInterface sni() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `StaticNestedInterface` like just declaring nested user defined datatype?

Comment: Yes, ```interface``` is similar to ```class``` in this case. When you declare ```StaticNestedInterface```, it becomes available for anyone to use. You still need to put a method in the ```SuperInterface``` for classes to implement. Super and nested interface would not behave any differently than two independent interfaces. This is because, unlike classes, interface cannot be private/protected.

Comment: two independent interfaces, you mean similar to package and subpackage concept.

Comment: packages does not affect ```interface``` usages. You could keep them anywhere in your project. I meant two independent interfaces as in defined anywhere in separate java files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a valid java code. Java compiler will create  `public static SuperInterface$StaticNestedInterface{}`

To use the nested interface `class Sub implements SuperInterface.StaticNestedInterface` then compiler will ask Sub class to implement the method declared on `StaticNestedInterface`

Answer (score -1):

```
interface StaticNestedInterface{    
  void a();
  void b();
}

interface SuperInterface extends StaticNestedInterface{
    void f();
}
class Sub implements SuperInterface{
    //now compiler require all methods(a, b and f)
}
```

Comment: In your answer, `StaticNestedInterface` is actually not nested interface, it is parent of `SuperInterface`.

Comment: @overexchange, you want to implement both interfaces, so you need to like this, or in the definition of class implement both interfaces